# Hibernate exception org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, properties

Hello I am currently developing small app to practice hibernate. I am trying to do one-to-many relation and I am stuck.

I have 2 Classes Question and Answer:

```
package com.sample;

import java.util.List;

public class Question {
    private int id;
    private String qname;
    private List<Answer> answers;

    public Question() {

    }

    public Question(int id, String qname, List<Answer> answers) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.qname = qname;
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQname() {
        return qname;
    }

    public void setQname(String qname) {
        this.qname = qname;
    }

    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public void setAnswers(List<Answer> answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }

}
```

and

```
package com.sample;

public class Answer {
    private int id;
    private String answername;
    private String postedBy;
    private Question question;

    public Answer() {

    }

    public Answer(int id, String answername, String postedBy, Question question) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.answername = answername;
        this.postedBy = postedBy;
        this.question = question;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAnswername() {
        return answername;
    }

    public void setAnswername(String answername) {
        this.answername = answername;
    }

    public String getPostedBy() {
        return postedBy;
    }

    public void setPostedBy(String postedBy) {
        this.postedBy = postedBy;
    }

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(Question question) {
        this.question = question;
    }


}
```

the configuration files are as follows:

question.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.sample.Question" table="question">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="qname"></property>

        <bag name="answers" table="answer" inverse="true" lazy="true"
            fetch="select" cascade="all">
            <key>
                <column name="question_id" not-null="true">
                </column>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.sample.Answer"></one-to-many>
        </bag>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

answer.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.sample.Answer" table="answer">
        <id name="id">
            <generator class="increment"></generator>
        </id>
        <property name="answername"></property>
        <property name="postedBy"></property>
        <many-to-one name="question" class="com.sample.Question"
            fetch="select">
            <column name="question_id" not-null="true">
            </column>
        </many-to-one>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

My main file looks like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;

public class StoreData {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory()
                .getCurrentSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();

        Answer ans1 = new Answer();
        ans1.setAnswername("java is a programming language");
        ans1.setPostedBy("Ravi Malik");

        Answer ans2 = new Answer();
        ans2.setAnswername("java is a platform");
        ans2.setPostedBy("Sudhir Kumar");

        Answer ans3 = new Answer();
        ans3.setAnswername("Servlet is an Interface");
        ans3.setPostedBy("Jai Kumar");

        Answer ans4 = new Answer();
        ans4.setAnswername("Servlet is an API");
        ans4.setPostedBy("Arun");

        ArrayList<Answer> list1 = new ArrayList<Answer>();
        list1.add(ans1);
        list1.add(ans2);

        ArrayList<Answer> list2 = new ArrayList<Answer>();
        list2.add(ans3);
        list2.add(ans4);

        Question question1 = new Question();
        question1.setQname("What is Java?");
        question1.setAnswers(list1);

        Question question2 = new Question();
        question2.setQname("What is Servlet?");
        question2.setAnswers(list2);

        session.persist(question1);
        session.persist(question2);

        t.commit();
//      session.close();
        System.out.println("success");

    }
}
```

When I run the app I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.sample.Answer.question
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.makeEntityManaged(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:314)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.sample.StoreData.main(StoreData.java:46)
```

Comment: I believe your question id is not generating. Your question id is remaining null when you are trying to save the question in the database.

This error happens when you try to assign null to a primitive data member of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by first adding the question and then setting the question to the answer.

```
    Question question1 = new Question();
    question1.setQname("What is Java?");

    Question question2 = new Question();
    question2.setQname("What is Servlet?");

    session.persist(question1);
    session.persist(question2);

    Answer ans1 = new Answer();
    ans1.setAnswername("java is a programming language");
    ans1.setPostedBy("Ravi Malik");
    ans1.setQuestion(question1);

    Answer ans2 = new Answer();
    ans2.setAnswername("java is a platform");
    ans2.setPostedBy("Sudhir Kumar");
    ans2.setQuestion(question1);

    Answer ans3 = new Answer();
    ans3.setAnswername("Servlet is an Interface");
    ans3.setPostedBy("Jai Kumar");
    ans3.setQuestion(question2);

    Answer ans4 = new Answer();
    ans4.setAnswername("Servlet is an API");
    ans4.setPostedBy("Arun");
    ans4.setQuestion(question2);

    session.persist(ans1);
    session.persist(ans2);
    session.persist(ans3);
    session.persist(ans4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate tries to save Answer which has reference to Question which has no id at the moment of saving.

Try to save Questions without answers first, then for each answer call setQuestion passing the saved ones. And just save the answers.